# LTC source code cloning to a new cryptocurrency?

Tags: wallet, litecoin, altcoin

**How do I edit the code to make my own currency, while changing the name?**

Hey, I have downloaded LTC source code from [its official github link.](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin) I want to create my own cryptocurrency identical to LTC, I might add some features later on, but for now it's not an issue. I am not a python programmer, and I have looked around to see if there was any tutorial on making a cryptocurrency by editing code.

**Which file is the code for wallet? How can I make my own cryptocurrency's wallet identical to most popular LTC(or BTC) wallets?**

**How do I sell my cryptocurrency?**

Let's say the coin's max supply is 50 million. When I create the currency how many coins should already be on the market? The purpose of my crytocurrency is to let people exchange money completely anonymously and secure in my country. Do websites(which sell cryptocurrency) have their own special wallet when they sell some currencies for dollars? Also do they sell the total tokens that they own as a company? Would they ever run out of tokens? How do they supply them?

When I make my own cryptocurrency, to make it more useful&convenient and popular I want people to be able to sell them whenever they want to in turn of my country's own currency (like dollars for example). How do I make that happen? Are there companies which would pay for it? I know I can submit my currency to exchange website and let people turn it into BTC then sell it for real money, but I want to sell it directly for real money. How do I accomplish it?

**When the coins first get published, what are the factors which will be effective on deciding its price in the first place? How does it get decided? Does the founder decide it? How was LTCs or BTCs price was determined?**

Comment: I know c programming @LukeMlsna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to familiarize yourself with the code that you have downloaded, which should give you an idea of what you will need to change.

**How many coins should already be on the market?**:
People often refer to how 'fairly' a cryptocurrency was launched. Most people consider a fair launch to be a launch where the creator or anyone else does not own a significant amount of the currency before it is publicly released. If a large amount of the currency was pre-mined, there is an argument to be made that the creator only launched the project in order to net themselves a profit by selling off their coins once they are worth a decent amount.

**Do websites have their own special wallet when they sell some currencies for dollars?**: I assume you are asking about the wallet used to store the new cryptocurrency, in which case this would likely be a modified version of existing software wallets that transacts with the new coin type.

**Do they sell the total tokens that they own as a company? Would they ever run out of tokens? How do they supply them?**: How many of the tokens that they hold are sold is up to them. How the new token is introduced into the economy is dependent on how the protocol functions. It could be the case that one specific key pair that belongs to the creator of the currency is allowed by the protocol to generate new coins at any time, in which case supply would not be an issue, and the creator could generate new coins as needed. If the token was able to be mined, then the creator could mine a large amount of the token to be sold before launching it.

**When I make my own cryptocurrency, I want people to be able to sell them for fiat currency**: If your token was listed on an exchange that deals specifically in fiat currency instead of only Bitcoin, users would be able to sell it that way, otherwise, you'd be looking at setting up your own exchange or platform where users can buy and sell the token, though there would likely be a great deal of legal licensing that would need to be taken care of for each jurisdiction where customers would be able to transact from.

**When the coins first get published, what are the factors which will be effective on deciding its price in the first place?**: If you had a pre-sale or Initial Coin Offering, then you would decide the initial sale price. If you launched the currency publicly without selling amounts of it, then the laws of supply & demand and other market forces would determine the price, as was the case with Bitcoin and Litecoin.